# Kio estas la objekto de "enskribi"?

Tags: verbs

Kio estas la objekto de "enskribi"?

Ĉu la afero en kiu oni skribas?
- Mi enskribas kajeron.

Aŭ la afero kiun oni skribas?
- Mi enskribas mian nomon.

Answer (score 3):

La dua. Komparu kun *enmeti, enhavi, enteni* kaj aliaj transitivaj verboj.

Kontraste, post netransitivaj verboj, la *-n* reprezentas la celon de moviĝo.

Eble ekzistas esceptoj, sed tiukaze tre malmulte.

Answer (score 3):

Mia unua reago estas ke oni plej ofte enskribas **sin** aŭ enskrib**iĝ**as.

Troviĝas ankaŭ multaj ekzemploj kie la objekto estas la afero skribita. Mi kontrolis multe pli da ekzemploj kaj trovis neniun en kiu la objekto estas la libro en kiu oni skribas.

- iu jam multajn fojojn glore enskribis sian nomon en la historion
- [Niaj germanaj samideanoj] enskribis per tio tre gravan paĝon en la historion de nia afero.
- Volu akcepti ĝin kiel ĝustan kaj enskribi la sumon en nian krediton.
- Ĉi tiun vorton Pentuer iafoje enskribis,
- eĉ pli aĝaj homoj komencis sin enskribi en la regimentojn.
- Enskribu ĉiujn, kiuj iris plendi kontraŭ mi,
- [V]i konstruis ponton kaj kalkule enskribis lignon por dudek mil rubloj, dum en efektiveco vi ne donis eĉ por cent rubloj?
- li bonvolu lin enskribi kiel ageman anon.
- Li luis domon apud la Taŭrida ĝardeno kaj sin enskribis en la anglan klubon
- ili enskribis en sia Biblio: “La dekan de Novembro de la jaro 1759 Dio donacis al ni filon”; kaj poste estis aldonite, ke la filo ĉe la bapto ricevis la nomojn “Johann Christoph Friedrich”.
- Vitalij rapideme enskribis en notlibreton ciferojn,
- Tigellinus silentis, kaj nur enskribis en sian memoron tiujn senatanojn